# Getting "undefined" when retrieving element's text content

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get the number of Total Videos Uploaded from http://www.youtube.com inside this element but I get "undefined class".

```
<a class="qZpD9d" href="//youtube.com/channel/UC64oAui-2WN5vXC7hTKoLbg/videos?feature=hovercard" target="_parent">6357 videos</a>
```

I'm trying get it via a user script. My script is:

```
function UploadedVideos () {
    var VideosUploaded = document.createElement('a');
    var Container = document.querySelector('.yt-user-info');
    VideosUploaded.id = 'uploaded-videos';
    VideosUploaded.className = 'uploadedN';
    Container.appendChild(VideosUploaded);

    var Total = document.querySelector('.qZpD9d').textContent;
    VideosUploaded.textContent = Total;
}
setTimeout(UploadedVideos, 1000);
```

For more info about this element you can go to any Youtube video, open developer tools, and search for `qZpD9d`.

class name it's the same for me for every Video i open Maybe the class name changed for every region however you can get Total Videos Uploaded Number when mouse hover on channel name it will popup small window contain Total Videos Uploaded Number for this channel see this image [https://i.imgsafe.org/c55f39c938.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYuf0.jpg)

Comment: I don't see any element with the class `qZpD9d` on the YouTube video page I'm looking at. Can you provide any more information about the element you're trying to read from?

Comment: @Hydrothermal go to `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNw4G4sBgYI`  open developer tools and search for `qZpD9d`

Comment: I don't think that class will be the same everytime you'll visit the page. I can't see it either.

Comment: See This image [Image Link](https://i.imgsafe.org/c55f39c938.jpg) when mouse hover on channel name will popup small window contain Total Videos Uploaded Number for this channel

Comment: @Hydrothermal it's the same for me for every Video i open Maybe the class name changed for every region however you can get Total Videos Uploaded Number when mouse hover on channel name will popup small window contain Total Videos Uploaded Number for this channel see this image [Image Link](https://i.imgsafe.org/c55f39c938.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The `.qZpD9d` element exists in an iframe generated by a function that triggers upon hovering over the channel's name. It doesn't exist on the parent page, so it can't be read without accessing the frame via `.contentWindow`, but the frame is cross-origin (apis.google.com) so that won't work either. I suggest looking into an AJAX solution querying the YouTube API or perhaps scraping the uploader's channel page.